# How to replace / in string using regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I've tested this regex and it finds the `/` character without issues.

Then why is this statement not replacing that character?

```
import re

str = 'bla / bla / bla'
str = re.sub(r'/\//g', ' - ', str)
```

Comment: Can you confirm how you tested the regex? I checked it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/35Zh40/1) using Python's regex rules and it doesn't match anything

Comment: You can use this r"[^\w]" to replace all non alpha numeric values.

Comment: For one, Python doesn't use `/.../g` like PCRE. Second, your pattern has `|` in it. Why would it match `/`? Lastly, `^` matches the start of string and `$` matches the end of the string. Why is that there?

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong line. Correct line pasted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must not have tested your regex against Python's engine, for which your syntax is off.  The `re.sub` function does not use delimiters.  Use this version:

```py
str = 'bla / bla / bla'
str = re.sub(r'\s+/\s+', ' - ', str)
print(str)  # bla - bla - bla
```